# Как вычесть из одного датафрейма второй в pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, анализ

Есть два датафрейма. Некоторые значения в них полностью одинаковые, но большинство - разные.
Нужно как то из одного датафрейма вычесть все значения второго датафрейма, чтобы первый стал уникальным. Подскажите, как лучше сделать?

df1

```
№   Фамилия Имя Отчество    № договора  Login   Остаток Доб.    Изм.
0   Иванов Иван Иванович    1           Ivan    100     13.01 16:31:11
1   Петров Петр Петрович    2           Petr    100     14.03 11:25:46
```

df2

```
 №  Фамилия Имя Отчество    № договора  Login   Остаток Доб.    Изм.
 0  Иванов Иван Иванович    1           Ivan    100     13.01 16:31:11
```

Новый датафрейм должен быть таким:

```
№   Фамилия Имя Отчество    № договора  Login   Остаток Доб.    Изм.
1   Петров Петр Петрович    2           Petr    100     14.03 11:25:46
```

То есть из df1 нужно вычесть df2

Comment: Добавьте примеры ваших датафреймов и результата, который хотите получить.

Comment: Добавил, постарался сделать понятнее, надеюсь получилось

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно объединить оба датафрейма с помощью [`concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html), а потом удалить из него дубликаты, используя [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) с параметром `keep=False`, который отвечает за удаление всех дубликатов.

```
In [4]: df1
Out[4]: 
   № Фамилия   Имя  Отчество  №.1 договора  Login  Остаток      Доб.  Изм.
0  0  Иванов  Иван  Иванович    1     Ivan    100    13.01  16:31:11   NaN
1  1  Петров  Петр  Петрович    2     Petr    100    14.03  11:25:46   NaN

In [5]: df2
Out[5]: 
   № Фамилия   Имя  Отчество  №.1 договора  Login  Остаток      Доб.  Изм.
0  0  Иванов  Иван  Иванович    1     Ivan    100    13.01  16:31:11   NaN

In [6]: pd.concat([df1, df2])
Out[6]: 
   № Фамилия   Имя  Отчество  №.1 договора  Login  Остаток      Доб.  Изм.
0  0  Иванов  Иван  Иванович    1     Ivan    100    13.01  16:31:11   NaN
1  1  Петров  Петр  Петрович    2     Petr    100    14.03  11:25:46   NaN
0  0  Иванов  Иван  Иванович    1     Ivan    100    13.01  16:31:11   NaN

In [7]: pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
Out[7]: 
   № Фамилия   Имя  Отчество  №.1 договора  Login  Остаток      Доб.  Изм.
1  1  Петров  Петр  Петрович    2     Petr    100    14.03  11:25:46   NaN
```

Answer (score 4):

Если у вас структура датафреймов идентичная, тогда есть простое решение:

```
res = df1[~df1.index.isin(df2.index)]
```

Получим

```
   № Фамилия   Имя  Отчество  №.1 договора  Login  Остаток      Доб.  Изм.
1  1  Петров  Петр  Петрович    2     Petr    100    14.03  11:25:46   NaN
```

Здесь появился еще один индекс потому что я копировал ваши исходные датафреймы из буфера обмена.